# Не понятен принцип работы wofstream

Tags: c++, linux, файлы, запись, xubuntu

Не могу понять в чем проблема в данном коде

```
#include <fstream>
std::wofstream fout ("FOUT.txt");
int main() {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
  fout << L"Привет hello\r\n";
  fout.close ();
  return 0;
}
```

Почему-то при запуске такого, казалось бы нормального кода он выдает ошибку, смысл которой я понять не могу

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__ios_failure'
> what():  basic_filebuf::_M_convert_to_external conversion error: iostream error
> Аварийный останов (стек памяти сброшен на диск)

Был бы очень благодарен любому направлению, куда копать и что делать.
P.S.: ОС: Xubuntu поcледняя LTS (вроде 20.04)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В процессе вывода файловый поток преобразует `wchar_t` символы в байты с помощью локаль-специфичного фасета [`std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt). Возможно данный фасет не может преобразовать кириллический символ. Попробуйте использовать [std::codecvt_utf8](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) фасет, предназначенный для преобразования кодировок `UCS2/UCS4` в `UTF-8`: `fout.imbue( std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>) );`